# Multiple popup links with them affecting each other

Tags: jquery

I have created 2 popup dialog box when you click on a link.

What I am trying to do:

If I open one popup and try to open another popup the opened popup box would disappear
Plus when I open them both and click on the close button they both close also the same as click on the link again - how can i separate this??

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/ZBfTy/

Comment: How could you open them both, if "I open one popup and try to open another popup the opened popup box would disappear"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them mutual exclusive, you could just run `close_modal();` before you open a box.

http://jsfiddle.net/Znarkus/ZBfTy/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you have two of them open to close one of them you would need to change your code like so:

```
    $('.close_modal').click(function(){
        //use the function to close it
        close_modal(this); // Passing the clicked link to the function
    });
});

//THE FUNCTIONS
function close_modal(link){
    //hide the mask
    $('#mask').fadeOut(500);
    //hide modal window(s)
    // using the clicked link to get the parent to close.
    $(link).parent().fadeOut(500);
}
```

Comment: Here try this one. I only just saw you where using the close function in two places. http://jsfiddle.net/5fRW4/

Answer (score 0):

you got problem in close function.
here is changed one.

```
 close_modal(this);

    function close_modal(t){
            //hide the mask
            $("#mask").fadeOut(500);
            //hide modal window(s)
            $(t).parent().parent().children('.modal_window').fadeOut(500);
        }
```